# Backing up small website to repository at github

Tags: git, github

I am working on developing a website and wanted to back it up on github. I took the following steps:

- Created repository on the site (github)
- In my local dev environment, I ran `git init` which created a .git dir
- In my local dev environment, I ran `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git`
- Now, I tried to add everything in my local box by `git add *`
- Tried to commit, it said

  `# On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean)`
- Tried to push everything to git remote by `git push -f origin branchname`. I got the following error:

  `Counting objects: 3644, done.
  Delta compression using up to 32 threads.
  fatal: Out of memory, calloc failed)

  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor`
- I even increased the size of post buffer, by running `git config http.postBuffer 709427264` but I got the same error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: why did you force push? how much data there is in your repo?

Comment: -f was just a habit. I have 50 MB data in the directory. Even if I don't use -f I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the output of `git fsck`.
If it tells you you have a a missing [blob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object), check [this link](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2012/02/git-push-fatal-unable-to-read-sha1/) for the solution.

Comment: # git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.